# How to push data to Highchart Networkgraph form firebase?

Tags: firebase, highcharts

**Hello.**

*When I use the chartData function to push data to the Highchart networkgraph, it does not work.

How can I get push data to graph from firebase.

Firebase data is in the desired format, so it works to retrieve the data.

The problem is to display it in the graph.

When I test the graph with the data values ​​that are now commented out, the graph works fine. Want to get the data from firestore.

For pie graph this way works to push data to the graph, so I thought it would work for network graph as well.

Anyone can help me?*

```
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';
import networkgraph from 'highcharts/modules/networkgraph';
import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import solidgauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { uniqBy, groupBy, sum, map, zip } from "lodash";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { IdeaService } from 'src/app/services/firestore/getidea.service'; 
import { Idea } from 'src/app/models/idea.model';
import { Chart } from 'highcharts';
more(HighCharts);
solidgauge(HighCharts);
networkgraph(HighCharts);
```

*Function to push data from firebase to networkgraph, this is not working!*

```
// Highchart - networkgraph - push data
private chartData(ideas: Idea[]) {
  const data = [];
  const grouped = groupBy(ideas, x => x.feeling);
  Object.keys(grouped).forEach(key => {
    const from = 'Valg'
    var value = grouped[key];
    console.log({ from: `${from}`, to: `${key}`})   
    data.push([`${from}`, `${key}`]);  
  });
    return data;
}
```

*I have try different format in data.push, without sucess.*

*Output from console.log in function chartData*

'["Valg", "ikke bra nok"]'
'["Valg", "sint"]'
'["Valg", "hat"]'

*And the graph under. When I use manual data, that are comment out now, the graph is displayed ok.*

```
// Lotus flower
plotLotusChart(ideas: Idea[]) {
  let myChart = HighCharts.chart('lotus', {
      chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        events: {
          load: function() {
            this.series[0].addPoint(['Valg'] );
          }
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        marginTop: 80
      },
      title: null,

      subtitle: {
            text: '<span style="color: white">Lotus blomsten</span>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
          keys: ['from', 'to'],
          layoutAlgorithm: { // added
            enableSimulation: true
          }
        }
      }, 
      series: [
        {
          marker: {radius: 30,
                  },
          dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  linkFormat: '',
                  allowOverlap: true 
                      },
        data: [this.chartData(ideas)],
             //     ['Valg', 'Følelser'],
             //     ['Valg', 'Behov'],
             //     ['Valg', 'Strategier'],
             //     ['Valg', 'Forventninger'],
             //     ['Valg', 'Harmoniøvelsen']
             // ],
          type: undefined,
        }]
  });
}
```

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property id of undefined

 at highcharts-more.js:111

 at Array.forEach ()

 at a (highcharts-more.js:111)

 at highcharts-more.js:111

 at Array.forEach ()

 at reingold-fruchterman.setCircularPositions (highcharts-more.js:111)

 at reingold-fruchterman.initPositions (highcharts-more.js:111)

 at reingold-fruchterman.start (highcharts-more.js:106)

 at highcharts-more.js:117

 at Array.forEach ()*

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on the online editor with sample data which I could work on? It doesn't have to be your current data from firebase, could be a few fixed values, just for testing.

Comment: Hi. I have add my code to JSFiddle, but I'm not an experian devloper in typescript, anguler and Ionic. So I'm not able to display the graph in JSFiddle. But all my code is there. Link to source are: https://jsfiddle.net/vilfredGangsoy/7hngjebo/19/

Comment: There is a simple reproduction of your code for networkgraph in pure JS - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tn7sgy4p/ this load callback breaks the chart in your case. That's how it looks like without it - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gkm83j7d/ Back to the whole case - the demo which you have shared doesn't work and I am not able to fix it. If you want to get help please reproduce your problem as simply as you can.